# Custom exception message

Tags: java, exception

I want to extend RuntimeException to create this specific exception:

```
class CompileLinkException extends RuntimeException {

    CompileLinkException(int shader) {
        int infoLogLength = glGetShader(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);
        String strInfoLog = glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLogLength);

        // set exception message = strInfoLog

        glDeleteShader(shader);
    }
}
```

How do i set a custom exception message? The only way i know is to call

```
super(message)
```

but this instruction must be the first statement in the constructor.

Comment: Please don't put handler code in your exception class. Put the handler code in the outer ```catch``` block where you'll catch this exception.

Comment: I think you people are not addressing the real problem here. Exception are just "vessels" and should not contain the log retrieving logic or any kind of logic. Those answer are discouraged. It would be absurdly funny to see an exception triggered inside a constructor of another exception because of it.

Comment: @opyate you are right, i'll remove glDeleteShader.

Comment: @Alexander glGetShaderInfoLog is a static method of a library i'm using, and i don't see what's wrong to get the error message here (it doesn't throw any exceptions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
super(glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, glGetShader(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH)));
```

Comment: In the case, the methods `glGetShader` and `glGetShaderInfoLog` must be static.

Comment: i thought of this solution, but i discarded because it was ugly :> but i'll accept your answer if this is the only option.

Comment: If you think this is too ugly, you could create a custom helper method to grab the log message instead of this one-liner... :)

Comment: @Veger i used the ugly solution :)

Answer (score 4):

I do not know for certain that the Exception code is only using the `getMessage()` method internally to use the message, but you could try to override this method and see whether it works for you:

```
class CompileLinkException extends RuntimeException {
    String strInfoLog;

    CompileLinkException(int shader) {
        int infoLogLength = glGetShader(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH);
        strInfoLog = glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infoLogLength);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return strInfoLog;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. The solution provided by @tibtof seems to be much better. But I'll leave this answer for completeness sake